# Using PHPSpec with array?

Tags: php, unit-testing, bdd, mockery, phpspec

I've been starting to use PHPSpec 2, and am loving it with Mockery, but ran into an issue I can't figure out.

I have an array returned by a static function, and I want to validate this array.  Make sure all the keys needed are there, etc.

I tried:

```
$systems = CacheFactory::getCacheSystems();
$systems->shouldBeArray();
```

As well as:

```
$systems = CacheFactory::getCacheSystems();
$this->spec($systems)->shouldBeArray();
```

But neither worked.  The first for obvious reasons, error'd saying `$systems` wasn't an object.  The second error'd saying I couldn't serialize a closure.  There are closures in the array (it's a config array), but I even tried filtering those out, to no avail.

Array example:

```
array(
'someCache' => array(
    'cache' => 'SomeCacheSystem',
    'checks' => function () { return isCacheActivated(); }
),
```

Is this possible with PHPSpec 2 currently?  Am I just missing something stupid, I am pretty new to the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume CacheFactory is your subject under specification:

```
<?php

namespace spec;

use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;
use Prophecy\Argument;

class CacheFactorySpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function it_has_all_the_keys_needed()
    {
        $this::getCacheSystems()->shouldBeArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bonus question, if you don't mind.  I can't seem to loop through the `$systems` array once I get it the way you specified